# Flask Restful accept a list in a post request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask Restful for my server API and am posting to the server a dictionary where one of the values is a list of dictionary's.

```
parser.add_argument('products_in_basket', type=list)
def post(self, user_id):
   args = parser.parse_args()
   print request.data
   print args['my_list']
```

The problem I have is args['my_list'] is only returning the first element of the list. Whereas I can see all list from request.data.

This is request.data

```
{"address_id":1,"my_list":[{"size":12,"colour":"red","id":34219,"quantity":1},{"size":10,"colour":"red","id":12219,"quantity":2},{"size":8,"colour":"red","id":5214,"quantity":3}],"payment_card_id":1}
```

This is args['my_list']

```
[u'colour', u'quantity', u'id', u'size']
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: so fetch it from request.data instead

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What are your parser `add_argument` options?  Is `products_in_basket` an actual key to the data that is requested?  Or are you trying to provide an arbitrary name and/or rename the dict?

Take a look at 
[Multiple Values & Lists](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html?highlight=reqparse#multiple-values-lists) from the *Request Parsing* documentation.

You may want to be doing something like this instead...

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('my_list', action='append')
```

Comment: Thank you, action='append' was the solution :)

Comment: Can you please update the link provided? It shows permission denied.

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the data like this:

```
for product in args.my_list:
        size = product.get('size')
        etc....
```

This will allow you to iterate over all the `dict` objects in the `my_list` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the location parameter in the add_argument function. This will specify that you are working with json and it will append the others elements in the list.

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('my_list', location='json')
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Without it, if I passed a single value in a list, it would appear like this : [['v','a','l','u','e']]